# How to insert array variable from Python to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

I have this issue passing the data from an array variable to the python javascript function. Below is the entire script

```
 array1 =[['X-val', 'Y-val'], [4, 5], [8, 12], [11, 14]];

self.response.out.write('<script type="text/javascript">'+
                        'google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});'+
                        'google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);'+
                        'function drawChart() { '+
                        'var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({0});' +
                        'var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("casestrend"));chart.draw(data);} '+
                        '</script> '.json.dumps(array1))
```

This is the javascript code which i want to convert to the python format wherein the array required for arrayToDataTable() will be fetched through queries. Currently static version of it (array1 above) doesn't work

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                                                                       
 google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});                                                        
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);                                                                                
 function drawChart() {                                                                                              
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['X-val', 'Y-val'], [4, 5], [8, 12], [11, 14]]);                
 var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));                                 
 chart.draw(data);                                                                                                 
 }                                                                                                                   
 </script>
```

Please let me know how to pass the data (array) from the python to the javascript so that the chart gets loaded.

Comment: What do you mean by Python? Which web framework are you using?

Comment: You probably mean `'...'.format(json.dumps(..))`...?!

Comment: I am using webapp2 framework for writing python codes. I was working on creating charts using the google charts wherein the data it needs is in array format. Having trouble passing the same from python array to javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current solution doesn't work because `format` (you missed it, right?) calls before strings concatenated.

In current case I would prefer concatenation over format to prevent braces escaping:

```
js_code = '''
          <script type="text/javascript">
          google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
          function drawChart() { 
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(''' + json.dumps(array1) + ''');
          var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("casestrend"));chart.draw(data);} 
          </script>
          '''
```

Comment: Note that this subtly changes the resulting string into a multi-line string. I doubt that it's going to be a problem... just saying.

Comment: @mhawke, thanks, that's true. Based on expected output in question it might be what author want.

Comment: Thank you so much @germn. Made my day!

Answer (score 2):

This will work.

```
array1 =[['X-val', 'Y-val'], [4, 5], [8, 12], [11, 14]];

self.response.out.write("""<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {{packages:["corechart"]}});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {{ 
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({0});
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("casestrend"));chart.draw(data);}}
    </script> """.format(json.dumps(array1)))
```